# How to redirect users after login facebook?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

Im know im on the right path.
Trying to figure out how to redirect users after logginin to a new view controller.

```
#import "FacebookLogin.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@implementation FacebookLogin
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
loginButton.readPermissions= @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    UIViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Main"];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you added FB App ID in you plist and specifed URL schemes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this......

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(Fb_Login) withObject:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void)Fb_Login
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             else if(session.isOpen)
             {
                 [self Fb_Login];
             }

         }];
        return;
    }
```

Comment: what do i need to import or declare ?

Comment: I get FBSession undeclared

Comment: FacebookSdk.Framework                                                                        in your appdelegate.h file   #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>        and Declare @property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;

Comment: in appdelegate.m for session expire when app is terminate  - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}

Comment: NEW SDK doesnot have FBSESSION